Rules of thumb for when to strive for perfection vs. good enough in practice
I’m trying to come up with good rules of thumb for when it is beneficial to strive for perfection in instrument practice vs. when doing so has diminishing returns and one should stop at “good enough” and move on.
On the one hand, I imagine that routinely stopping at good enough is essentially training yourself to play sloppily, and on the other hand, obsessing over a single thing may lead to burnout or injury, and sometimes leaving a difficult piece or exercise and returning to it later after building some “supporting skills” can help overcome a challenge.
So, concretely, for each of the following types of activities, where would you draw the line?

Preparing a repertoire piece for a show
Learning a new piece (slightly above one’s level, not for a show)
Sight reading (slightly below one’s level, for fluent reading)
Daily reading practice (“a piece a day” kind of thing, for extending one’s vocabulary)
Technique (scales, arpeggios, rhythm, other technical exercises)
Other activities I forgot?

I usually have a mix of these activities I work on at any given time and I struggle with the urge to perfect everything.
Thanks!

Striving for perfection and accepting things as good enough is not an either/or. You can do both at the same time. I think what you might want to consider is tempo. Slow down until you play it right. Speed it up over time while keeping it right.

Anyway, I think this is an interesting question that might give some ideas about what may count when we go for practicing.

@ToddWilcox, There's a super-concise way to remember that advice. IDK who said it first, but it's "Don't practice your mistakes!"  Also, if they ask, "why not?" you can answer, "Because practice doesn't make perfect. Practice makes permanent."

Who is your intended audience?

In addition to Michael Curtis's question (intended audience), what's the genre?  The answer really depends whether you're talking about classical, jazz, pop, etc.  Also, does "show" = "recital"?

I work as a professional pianist and keyboardist for a music theater department. I have learned and performed something like 2000 songs in the last three years (according to my forscore) and many of them have been virtuoso, difficult pieces for world class venues. What I can tell you is, when you are actually working, perfectionism is profoundly harmful. I strive simply to be consistently correct. Here is my little algorithm, which presupposes some technique.
How to learn music

Attempt to play the whole piece, either by ear, or from the score. If the piece is so hard that you don't even know what is going on, it is too hard for you. Pick an easier piece, get a teacher, or, if you were hired to play it, get a sub immediately.
Once you have read through the piece and decided that it is possible within the available timeframe, read through it again. A good deal of issues will solve themselves. Fake everything else as if you were onstage in Carnegie Hall.
Now, go back and figure out what the greatest technical challenges are. This is a good time to do an analysis of the piece. I highly recommend just writing down observations on some legal paper or a text document think a list like this:

The A section begins on measure 5 after a brief intro that is composed of the orchestra part from the from the first phrase of the A section
The A section is composed of a dramatic opening motif, followed by a series of suspensions.
There is a difficult technical section in the B theme that repeats over and over again, and which I got wrong.


Pick a part to work on that maximizes exposure. This means, if there is a difficult accompaniment pattern that happens 150 times and will sound dumb if you can't play it, start with that before tacking a weird fingering that happens once.
Find a technical solution to your problem very slowly. This can mean a change of fingering, a change of embouchure, anything it needs to be to make sure you can play it correctly.
Once you have solved your technical problem, ingrain one small passage pertaining to it with the following technique

Using a metronome, find a tempo at which you can play it correctly with minimal effort.
Repeat the passage correctly 5 times in a row at this tempo. If you mess something up, start your count over. If you mess up the same thing several times, select a smaller section, reduce complexity of the section (only playing one of the hands), or reduce the tempo.
Once you have found a comfortable tempo, and repeated it five times correctly at this tempo, decrease the tempo in increments of 5 clicks on a standard metronome until you hit the bottom of the metronome. (40 bpm is fine on digital metronomes.) Attempt to play it exactly correctly with all articulations, fingerings, and in exactly correct time at each of these slower tempos. This is more difficult than it sounds and will expose a lot of fakery that worked at the comfortable tempo. Repeat step 2 as new issues pop up.
Once you can play the passage comfortably, correctly, and reliably at the lowest setting on your metronome, return to your previous comfortable setting, and play it again. Correct any mistakes with step 2.
Increase your tempo by 5 clicks (or 10-15 bpm), and check it at all of these higher tempos on your metronome. Once you have found the upper limit of your playing, go back down five clicks and slowly increase the tempo in increments of 2-4bpm or 1 click. Once you find your upper limit again, stop. Move on. You have done what you can with this passage, and you should be exhausted from the concentration.


Make sure that you can incorporate this passage into a larger passage, by attempting a few measures on either side.
Do this a couple of times for a couple of important passages, and then take a significant break. You shouldn't practice for more than 2 hours at a time, but you also shouldn't practice less than an hour or two a day if you want to make progress.
Keep track of what parts of the process are working the best, and which part are not. If you are having a hard time playing fast, consider exercises. or fast repertoire. If you can't read through a piece all the way through with fakery, start practicing your sight-reading more by setting a metronome to a new piece and getting through it by staying in time no matter what you have to botch or leave out.
Return to whatever you have been working on the next day, and see what has improved, and what has not. You should approach it with the attitude of a scientist, with a dispassionate interest and no ego attached to outcome.

This process effectively balances correctness and practicality for me. Tweak it constantly as you see fit. I certainly do!

This is an amazing answer, thank you for that!

Glad I could help! Let me know if you have any thoughts!

It's been said many times, and I endorse it: amateurs practise till they get it right, pros practise till they can't get it wrong.
There are many different criteria for learning something.
True, if it's for a show, gig, or recording where it needs to be right for the show, or save precious time in the studio. So here, a piece needs to be absolutely learned 'off pat' - or if it's a piece with ad lib bits, the format, chord sequence, etc., have to be spot on.
Other pieces may be tackled to provide some insight into a particular skill - dynamics, reading layout, a special technique, etc. Once those are played well, it really doesn't matter too much about the rest of the piece, it was just a vehicle.
Some attributes of playing are setting you up for future, unknown challenges. Scales and arpeggios come to mind, as they're the backbone of many pieces so far un-tackled. So those are ripe for working on for many reasons, dexterity being just one.
Sight-reading is a tricky one. Do little, and it'll never improve. And use the metronome to make it more arduous! But at the same time (or just after!) do the antithesis - improvisation. Both are tremendously important to any player, but one too often gets neglected for the other.
So, as far as the question goes, bearing in mind we're all different in the way we learn, and assimilate knowledge, split up the practice time into specific areas. Also consider sometimes doing a melange of learning in a session, other times, simply concentrating on on skill, but for a shorter time. Time is another factor. Personally, often 10-15 mins is my limit before my concentration wanes enough for any longer to be unproductive.
All of this will be affected by what kind of music you play/want to play. Solo, in a rock band, in a jazz ensemble, in an orchestra, all of which will bring their own rather different attributes to what 'perfection' is in reality...

Brilliant answer, Tim.
Thank you for your insights and wisdom, sir.

My rule of thumb, no matter what the musical endeavor, is to "Do Your Best".
It's possible to overthink such things, and it sounds like you have a lot on your plate. And kudos to you in that it sounds like you are a busy musician.
In my own experience, as a band leader for a combo playing classic rock and classic country, perfection is a relative term. Each player must show up to rehearsal having learned the songs, and rehearsing together is the time to work on timing, inflection, beginnings and endings, and for soloist(s) to find out if they can deliver the goods in front of a small audience (the band).
Each player must show up to the gig having endeavored to perfect the songs, as much as that is possible. And failure in delivering the solo bits, at a live gig, are normally related to that nervousness at keeping it all together in front of a larger, paying audience.
In your world, and it sounds like you are a proper musician in an orchestra, performing off the sheet music is a more exacting enterprise. You have to play the notes and chords exactly as they are displayed on the music stand there.
Any mistakes in timing, inflection, or sweetness will be lost in the noise of a fuller orchestra pit, but will be painfully obvious in a three piece or five piece combo.
The conductor or band leader will be your critic of course, and will also be your biggest fan when you deliver brilliantly. But remember that YOU will always be your biggest critic, and that's as it should be.
Take your time, practice patiently, remain inner-calm, remember that perfection is a relative term, and Do Your Best.

What do you do if the players don't live up to the demands? In my bands, quite often nobody gets paid, and the most important thing is to make sure that everyone has a good time, feels welcome and wants to come to rehearsal again.

I get where you are coming from, piiperi Reinstate Monica.
Not every musician works the paying gigs.
But in the end, the audience has to be satisfied, and the music has to be of such a quality that people will want to come see you perform again.
Otherwise, what's the point?
In sports, not everybody gets a trophy.
In music, it's even more discriminating and cut-throat.
The band or combo must deliver, or there will never be another gig.

It helps to have a plan. Learning and improving will not happen in one session, it takes time. And time is the limiting factor - how to distribute limited time on different aspects of improving.
The common way to create that plan is to work together with a musician that knows how to teach (not necessarily the same as beeing a good musician in other respects). A grown-up person would preferrably book a number of sessions with a teacher / tutor and then work on whatever they suggest.
All instruments I know of have some kind of standard progressive learning material. You start with the very simple and go on to more and more advanced. In my experience it is very good to go back to the very simple now and then and make it better. This material most often is and example on how to work on the technique on your instrument. Examples may be (different on different instruments):

all the scales
all the intervals
very soft to very strong
different articulations
intonation
speed

The point is that you will never be perfect, all great musicians works on this every day.
Another point might be to improve your musicianship. One way to rank performances is to understand how it influences the listeners feelings. Listening to great musicians and imitating is one way. Recording yourself (most every phone has a recording app) and listening will show where you stand.
Knowledge of the standard repertoir for your instrument is another aspect. Music has different genres that work differently. Baroque music is different from big-band-jazz and is different from Beethoven which is different from death metal. Listening, trying to understand and mimicing are all parts of your progress work.
Defining short-term goals is one way that works for some, and not for others. I suggest short-term goals firstly. One short term goal could be to define the effort you want to put into training (an input goal). You might as example have as goal to play at least one hour every day the coming week. (Playing a minimum of 15 minutes every day is my recommended minimum for any instrument). Or you might have as goal to be able to play every scale, major and minor, during one session (an output goal). Reaching this necessitates you to know and rehearse every scale.
Don´t forget to have fun. Personally (I play the bassoon) I like to play jazz songs I know from my heart and transpose them on the fly to different keys.
